# Apache Web Server Stopped

Tags: apache, xampp

I recently installed Xampp on Fedora 31, Everything is okay, except... Apache web server is not working, when I push "start all", it activates Mysql, and ProFTPD, but Apache Web server appears "Stopped".
I've have tried to change port from 80 to 8000, and ssl port 4431 ....it does not work!.

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/quick-docs/getting-started-with-apache-http-server/

https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/quick-docs/getting-started-with-apache-http-server/

It worked for me with this

```
Install HTTPD packages.

# dnf install httpd -y

Start the HTTPD service.

# systemctl start httpd.service
```

Answer (score 0):

What I did is: Go to the terminal and type `sudo service apache2 restart (or start)` (You might need the sudo command to do this)